# How to get mock events in Boto3

Tags: boto3, boto, moto

I have an s3 bucket that has an SNS registered to it. The SNS notification goes onto an SQS which is monitored by a lambda that I'd like to test.

I'm using moto to mock my s3 calls in my test. When I set up my test, I put an object into my S3 bucket. And then I also have a json document that I mocked up that reflects the event that would be generated and passed to my lambda (which is receiving events from S3).

My question is, rather than mocking the event json manually, would I be able to use moto/boto to generate it?

Comment: What's the problem with static json? it's not a big document and largely unchanged, can be borrowed entirely from AWS console test events.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it per se. Was just looking to see if there was a cleaner/easier way to do it. Based on the lack of a "oh actually it's super simple just do x" answer thus far I'll probably be sticking with the json.

Comment: You could take a look at deploying everything with localstack and writing custom tests around that.